# Обработка запросов к изображениям Flask

Tags: python, flask

Делаю копию сайта, есть такой код:

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response,
@app.route('/<path:url>/')
def routing(url):
    url = request.path
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, 
    like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}
    body_request = requests.get('https://донор.ru/'+ url, headers=headers)
    response = make_response(body_request.text)
    return response
```

Т.е. при каком либо запросе страницы я просто запрашиваю ее у донора и возвращаю html. Скрипты и css скачаны и на моём сервере, а вот с картинками засада. С загрузкой страницы на сервер поступают запросы типа
GET /img/4325016a1a.jpg/
GET /img/item/45501632da.jpg/
Таких картинок и директорий на сервере нет и заранее создать все директории и скачать картинки не вариант. Как можно обрабатывать эти запросы, что бы скачивать картинки на свой сервер в соответствующую запросу директорию? Или лучше вообще обрабатывать эти запросы не сохраняя ничего у себя, не трогая при этом урлы картинок в возвращаемом html (урлы картинок не должны вести на сайт-донор) . Такое возможно на flask ? )